# Security testing resources

Tags: security-testing, training

Can anyone recommend any good security testing resources?  Although I have a basic security skillset, I'd like to improve this.  Some of the training I've seen online however seems kind of sketchy.  Resources would have to be a reasonable price.

> I know that there's no one answer for this, but still, hoping for some recommendations.

Comment: Not really an answer, but one big thing to keep in mind about security is that a lot of it isn't necessarily related to your app, but rather the environment your app runs in. One of the best things you can do to test security is to set up the app in a fresh environment. If the security measures aren't part of the scripted install/setup process, it's just begging to get breached when someone forgets a step like... locking down `iptables` or forgetting a database or file permission or something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For web application security you might find it useful - https://owasp.org/

Comment: Although the other answers were very good, and I already have some experience with OWASP, I have to say that OWASP is still the best resource out of what was presented.

Answer (score 11):

[image: How to Break Software Security]

[This book](https://www.amazon.in/How-Break-Software-Practical-Testing/dp/0201796198) has a lot of good ideas you can try.

https://books.google.co.in/books/about/How_to_Break_Software.html?id=RbZQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Very good book to pick up & have on your shelf.

Answer (score 6):

Also consider doing [threat models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model) - IME, when testers are part of the threat model process, they generally find security issues nobody else does.

Comment: Hadn't come across threat models before - thanks, sounds useful!

Answer (score 2):

If security is important to the success of your application, I would suggest hiring professionals from firms such as HP, Cigital, SecurityCompass, etc and observing how they approach it. Books and websites are one thing, but you really need mentorship too...

Answer (score 2):

http://www.hackthissite.org/pages/index/index.php

Googles site for security testing: http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/ - really useful.

Try going through both sites with a copy of the book suggested by Alan - they really complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

For web application security you could try with some tools like

- **Burp Suite** 
  http://portswigger.net/burp/
- **Grendel Scan** 
  http://grendel-scan.com/

Comment: Is Grendel Scan still maintained?  I see the last blog post for it was in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this site recommended recently as a good resource for those wanting to practice security testing:

http://hackademic1.teilar.gr/

Comment: Interesting.  Starting to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This may help - http://www.guru99.com/ethical-hacking-tutorials.html

You can also learn about Penetration Testing [here](http://www.guru99.com/learn-penetration-testing.html)