# Any testing resource for security testing of mobile web applications

Tags: tools, security-testing

i have gone through the following question [security sources](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/304/security-testing-resources) and found testing resources for testing desktop and web applications, any realtime resource to test an mobile web applications?

Comment: Is there a specific challenge that you are encountering with mobile web applications vs web applications?  Most of the security testing is done against the server which will be pretty much identical for either a web application or mobile web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part mobile web applications behave exactly the same as their counterparts on a desktop.  Even if the user input is slightly different, the mobile application is still interfacing with the device running it in a similar fashion, sending along similar protocols and being interpreted on the back end is as well (likely).  If information is being stored locally about the user, including detailed personal information that will vary from OS to OS, but still isn't that much of a departure.

OWASP has some mobile specific info, but in all likelihood you can use the same information from your previous research for base level security testing.  If you're looking to go deeper than basic security coverage that a functional tester would perform, the folks here may be more helpful:  https://security.stackexchange.com/